# Android - remember me function for saving radio buttons in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android development and I am wondering if there is a way to have some sort of remember me function where it allows a user to have an option whether to save the current state of radio buttons.... a bit like a remember me function on a login apart from using a set of radio buttons instead....any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
@Override

    /*
     * Holding the data for the radio buttons from the xml file
     */
    RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question1);
    gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer1A:
                ans1 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer1B:
                ans1 = 2;
                break;
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Yes, they are called `SharedPreferences`, save to a DB, or save to a file

Answer (score 0):

To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your Code:

```
SharedPreferences _prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "values_to_remember", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
int ansA = "ans1";
int value = _prefs.getInt(ansA, 1(default value));
```

To edit and save preferences

```
_edit().putInt(ansA , 1).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private RadioButton button;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferences=getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE);
    button=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.question1);
    button.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("set", false));
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("set", isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

You will have use a sharedpreference. And store the state of radiobutton in it.